# Getting feature file path within BehatContext

Tags: php, bdd, behat

I have a `FeatureContext` class, whose methods implement step definitions for my feature scenarios.

Is it possible to obtain information about current scenario or feature within `FeatureContext` class? To be specific, **I need the path of the feature file**, so I can create directory paths relative to `dirname('file.feature')`.

The context class resides somewhere in vendor directory structure, i.e. far away from the actual feature file, so getting the path using `__DIR__` would not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Sascha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find an answer to my question: "hooks"

```
class MyContext implements Context
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     */
    public function beforeScenario(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
    {
        var_dump($scope->getFeature()->getFile());
    }
}
```